# Windows 8 pinned website tile

Tags: javascript, windows

I am getting confused with this windows 8 website tile badge notification. 
On microsoft website it says you just need simple xml file which you access through meta tag polling-uri. Examples they have shown is all in .net and javascript. My question is how you update the badge and clear it using javascript.How javascript will know the new status of website and how it will update the xml file to push notification on tile. Is there a way to do by java server side. Thank you

This is what I am talking about:

[MSDN Blog: Pinned Sites in Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/04/03/pinned-sites-in-windows-8.aspx)

Comment: I'm a bit lost...what do you mean by "website tile badge notification"?

Comment: He meant the tiles that you pinned to your screen that pushes a notification to it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set up a notification server enabling toast notifications and you need to set the notification channel interval of update .